# Combine two cells in sumproduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, worksheet-function, sumproduct

I have below table

```
 ID      NEW                   ASSIGN
 123                       6/18/2015 15:48
 124    6/18/2015 11:13 
 125                       6/18/2015 9:22
 126                       6/17/2015 21:01
 127                       6/17/2015 20:30
 128                       6/16/2015 13:57
 129    6/15/2015 10:21 
 130                       6/15/2015 9:45
 131                       6/5/2015 8:26
 132    6/4/2015 11:02  
 133                       6/3/2015 16:01
 134                       6/18/2015 1:41
 135                       6/16/2015 3:37
 136    5/18/2015 18:36 
 137                       6/16/2015 3:33
 138                       5/11/2015 15:27
```

In cell E1:F1

```
 Aging  =SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A17>128),--(A2:A17<136),

 --(NETWORKDAYS(C2:C17+0,TODAY()+0,0)<=30))
```

which gives me 5 as result.

Now, the requirement is to make use of NEW column value in place of blank cells in ASSIGN column.

Copy-paste NEW column values to ASSIGN cell is not an option, I am stuck with this.

Comment: I would use a formula similar to `IF(ISBLANK(assign), new, assign)`.  Entered as an array formula, it should pull in your values as needed.  You can replace your current references to `assign` with that new reference instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to check if @Byron answer in the comment works. It works, the result is 7.

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A17>128),--(A2:A17<136), --(NETWORKDAYS(IF(ISBLANK(C2:C17),B2:B17,C2:C17)+0,TODAY()+0,0)<=30))}
```

Comment: Yep It works, but when I use dynamic range, it appends unnecessary #NA at the end of array

Comment: Can you share the formula that you use? The result is just in one cell, so I don't understand where you see the formed array.

Comment: Here is it.  Iget #value result. If you press F9,you can get instant result. =SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1_ID="ABC"),--(NETWORKDAYS(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1_ASSIGNTIME),Sheet1_NEWTIME,Sheet1_ASSIGNTIME)+0,TODAY()+0,0)<=30)) . Here I have used dynamic cell range  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4969,0,0,COUNTA(WIR!$B$2:$B$4969),1)

Comment: I've tested that on named ranges exactly the same way as your first formula and it does work `=SUMPRODUCT(--(colA>128),--(colA<136), --(NETWORKDAYS(IF(ISBLANK(colC),colB,colC)+0,TODAY()+0,0)<=30))`. Where is your first formula connected to your dynamic range? I see no connection to it.

Comment: Added data of mine. That is the result which I get

Comment: I see the problem - you get errors, because you resize the rows amount in the range to `COUNTA(WIR!$B$2:$B$4969)`. `COUNTA` does not count blank cells. In your example you have 9 blank cells,therefore the resized range does not include those 9 last cells, thus you get errors there. I cannot help more, as you did not tell us what is that `OFFSET` formula assigned to. Is it assigned to a named range? Also,this does not seem anymore the problem of this question. I suggest you creating a separate question, as now additional formula is involved, and the conditions in the main formula are different.

Comment: Ya. You are right @ZygD. That's the root cause. Thanks.